# How to control Jersey serialization using query params

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, jersey-2.0

I am looking for a dynamic way to control the response object coming back from a request using query params.

I am using Jersey 2.x and Hibernate 4 for managing entities along with some Spring sprinkles for security etc.The problem is that Jersey is not serializing the attached entity but only the base entity. I am currently using the `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4`. that gives me some of the flexiblity to handle how to load child and parent entities using JPA fetch=Eager etc. However I really want to make this dynamic.

I tried a simple dynamic loading by specifying a `?with=<someentity>` to specify what entities to attach. When fetching the entity I use reflection to call the getter for someentity and it attaches the entity successfully but when sending the entity out it is not serializing the attached entity.

Here is a super simple example of what I am trying to do. This is really just a piece parted together but the idea is there. The problem is when I get the Campaign object back form the server it is not serializing the entities that are attached by calling loadEntity.

```
@Path("campaign")
public class CampaignResource {


    @GET
    @Path("{entity_id}")
    public Campaign find(@PathParam("entity_id") final Long id, @QueryParam("with") final String with) {
        T entity = repository.findOne(id);
        load(entity, with);
        return entity;
    }



    /**
     * This is used to attach entities that are requested via the api.
     * 
     * @param entity
     * @param with
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected void loadWithEntities(T entity, final String with) {
        String[] withFields;
        if (with.contains(",")) {
            // Split the with clause into separate values
            withFields = with.split(",");
        } else {
            // Single with clause
            withFields = new String[] { with };
        }

        for (String field : withFields) {
            final String getterMethodName = getMethodGetterForField(field);
            Method method = null;
            try {
                method = entityClass.getMethod(getterMethodName);

                if (method != null) {
                    logger.info("Loading entity " + getterMethodName);
                    // Some odd reason we have to assign the variable so that it
                    // is attached.
                    final Object attached = method.invoke(entity);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Unable to find method name %s ", getterMethodName, e);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey has the [Entity Data Filtering](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html) to handle this use case. Hopefully you are using a later version of Jersey, as Jackson is not supported until (somewhere between 2.14 :-) and 2.16. Too lazy to check when. I'm guessing you are using the `jersey-media-json-jackson`. You will know if you version is supported if it pulls in the `jersey-entity-filtering` dependency. You don't need to add anything else.

You only need to configure three thing:

1. Register the `SelectableEntityFilteringFeature`.
2. Configure the query parameter name.

   ```
   .property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME, "with")
   ```

There are different types of filtering features, but here is the [section on query param filtering](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html#ef.selectable.annotations). There's not much information, because well, there's not much information to tell. All you really need to know is how to configure, and it work as you expect, i.e. `?with=prop1,prop2,prop3`

Comment: This looks exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I can't wait to give it a try.

Comment: Any ideas on how to support wildcards. I would love to be able to do something like. with=advertiser.*,agency.* to fetch all the fields. I am looking at the ScopeResolver but don't see anything that will allow me to select all the fields. Thanks again.